# How can I update my GUI score one point at a time?

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

If a player receives X amount of points for doing something in my game I want the scoreboard to update showing each number from 0 - X very briefly. I'm going for an analog style scoring system like those old clocks where you can watch the numbers change, except the change will happen quickly because hundreds of points can be added at the same time.

Currently, X amount of points are updated instantly when points are awarded:

```
/****************************** Platform Collision ***************************/

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in coll.contacts)
        {   
            newPlayerHeight = transform.position.y;

            // Don't count the first jump
            if(newPlayerHeight < 0){
                newPlayerHeight = 0;
            }

            // If the player jumps down, don't reduce points
            // Add a tolerance for variable collision positions on same platform
            if(newPlayerHeight < oldPlayerHeight + -0.05f){
                newPlayerHeight = oldPlayerHeight;
            }

            // Send the height to the Score class
            Score.SP.updateScore(newPlayerHeight);

            oldPlayerHeight = newPlayerHeight;
        }
    }

/******************************* Score class *********************************/

public void updateScore (float newScore)
    {
        // Display GUI score
        score = (int)(newScore * 76);
        guiText.text = "Score" + score;

    }
```

I messed around with a for-loop to try and achieve this but got nowhere close.

Comment: Just maintain an actual score and a displayed score. And then in each update call, increase the displayed score by a set amount, depending on how fast you want it to count up.

Comment: @Bart - Any chance of getting an implementation of this? I've been working at it for awhile and my brain cells are hot with emotion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created this code, which solves your problem. I am currently using it in my own game.

The main idea of the `ScoreManager` class is to keep tract of the score and update it every frame. It uses a `Stack` to keep track of the score to be added, that way we don't have a magic number increasing the score.

So when the player earns a new point just call the `addScore()` function then the `ScoreManager` class will handle the updating all by itself.

It will have a thread always running which will increase from `currentScore` to `newScore` digit by digit, that way the change is observable by users like you wanted.

**The thread was added to reduce the "lag" you are experiencing in the other question you posted**: [Why is my game lagging huge when I call a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100759/why-is-my-game-lagging-huge-when-i-call-a-method)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUIText score;

    private int currentScore = 0;
    public int scoreToUpdate = 0;

    private Stack<int> stack;

    private Thread t1;
    private bool isDone = false;

    void Awake() 
    {
        stack = new Stack<int>();
        t1 = new Thread(updateScore);
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void updateScore()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(stack.Count > 0)
            {
                int newScore = stack.Pop() + currentScore;

                for(int i = currentScore; i <= newScore; i++)
                {
                    scoreToUpdate = i;
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // Change this number if it is too slow.
                }

                currentScore = scoreToUpdate;
            }

            if(isDone)
                return;
        }
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        score.text = scoreToUpdate + "";
    }

    public void addScore(int point)
    {
        stack.Push(point);
    }

    public void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        isDone = true;
        t1.Abort();
    }
}
```

I plan to turn this code into a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so that there is only one instance of this class in my game. I highly recommend you do the same.

Comment: Trying to get this to work in my game but I'm experiencing some strange behavior. Getting this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MikesController.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D coll) (at Assets/Scripts/MikesController.cs:88)

Comment: This is the line the error is referring to: ScoreManager.SM.addScore(((int)(newPlayerHeight * 76)));

Comment: Why are you calling `addScore()` in such an odd manner? What is `SM`? All you need is a reference to the script component and just call the function. Or make the class static.

Comment: First game. I'm doing a lot of odd things.

Comment: I created a reference to the script component and called it that way. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Assuming that your reference is `SM` then you call it like this: `SM.addScore(integerNumber);`

Comment: So i got it working ... but it's not working in the way I was hoping it would. It's not displaying to the GUI every number between the old score and the new score. It just updates the score with the new score.

Comment: @LooMeenin check the update I made to the answer. It will solve the problem by adding a thread so that it also solves the other question you posted.

Comment: I gave this a try and it still doesn't increase the score digit by digit. Also, the first time I tried it Unity crashed. I was able to run it once after opening Unity, but if I play it more than once it always crashes.

Comment: The crash was because of the editor, the thread never died. I already added that fix above, just copy paste the code. On my end it does increase it digit by digit, it just happens really fast. I also know it is happening because the `for loop` ensures that it does. Put a delay in that for loop if you want it slower.

Comment: Awesome! I added a bit more code, it has the delay. Play with that number until you get the effect you are going for. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a Unity coroutine?
It could be easier to implement, starting a coroutine and letting the frame update between each increase in the score would be a simple way to get things going.

A coroutine allows access to `yield return null` this will wait until the end of the current frame to continue with the function.

```
...
StartCoroutine(AddtoScore(ValuetoAdd));
...
...
public IEnumerator AddtoScore(int value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        currentScore++;
        guiText.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
        yield return null;
    }
}
...
```

However the downside of this is that if you score again while it is adding points it may create some graphical problems.

On the other hand you could place it in the Update function the same style. Unity calls the Update function once every frame.

```
...
void Update(){
    if(currentScore < scoreToUpdate) {
        currentScore++;
        guiText.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
    }
}
...
```

However both of these methods do require that the class they are in inherits from monodevelop:

```
public class Scoring : MonoBehaviour
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution, using HOTween (which is free and open source). Note that it wont show all numbers, just as many as it can within `transitionTime` seconds.

```
using Holoville.HOTween;

...

int displayScore = 0;

public void updateScore (int newScore)
{

    if (oldScore != newScore) 
    {
        float transitionTime = .2f;
        HOTween.To(this, transitionTime, "displayScore", newScore);
    }

}

public void Update() {
    guiText.text = "" + displayScore
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: HOTween : "MohawkMike (ScoreManager).displayScore" is missing, static, or not public. The tween for this property will not be created.