# Why is my game lagging huge when I call a method?

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I've been messing around trying to create an analog style scoring system for my game that I am building with Unity3D and I've noticed a huge lag when I call AnalogScoreProcessing() from the updateScore() function:

```
/******************************** Update Score ********************************/

public void updateScore (int newScore)
{
    // Send the old score/new score to AnalogScoreProcessing()
    if (oldScore != newScore) 
    {
        AnalogScoreProcessing(oldScore, newScore);
    }

    // Display GUI score
    oldScore = newScore;
    guiText.text = "" + oldScore;
}

/*************************** Analog Scoring System ****************************/

void AnalogScoreProcessing(int oldScore, int newScore){
    for(int i = oldScore; i <= newScore; i++){
        print (i);
    }
}
```

Do I have to create a new thread or a co-routine to complete the looping task while the remaining parts of updateScore() are carried out? I've never done any threading but I have used co-routines. I'm just not sure what I should be using here.

Comment: What are example values of `oldScore` and `newScore` that are causing problems?

Comment: I increment the score by about 150 every time the character reaches a new platform. The player lags or pauses while the loop prints to console.

Comment: So you're lagging because you're writing 150 lines to the [debug log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-print.html)?

Comment: Yeah, my character stops mid jump and waits for the lines to write to console.

Comment: Then don't print 150 lines to the console.  Instead print a single line like `string.Format("oldScore: {0}; newScore: {1}", oldScore, newScore)`  Or if you absolutely must print 150 lines to the console, build them in a `StringBuilder` and print that one long string.

Comment: Maybe I asked this question a little prematurely as my final goal is not to print to console. But I do want to display each number from oldScore to newScore on the GUI. so 0, 1, 2, ... 150 if oldScore is 0 and new score is 150.

Comment: Yes, you should measure your performance with the easiest and most straightforward implementation before trying to optimize.  There is no reason to believe that the performance of printing to the debug log file will be related to the performance of updating text in the GUI.  See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: I posted my solution to this problem on your very similar and related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100029/how-can-i-update-my-gui-score-one-point-at-a-time

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use coroutines here.

You basically want the players to see the effect of counting up right?

So say you want to display a count up to the user being +1 to the user ever few frames or so so the count up will be perceivable.

Try...

I would do it like this

```
int current =0;
int target = 0;
float percentateOfTarget = 0;
float step = 0.1f;
IEnumerable AnalogScoreProcessing()
{
    while(current <= target)
    {
      current = (int)Math.Ceiling(Mathf.Lerp(current, target, percentateOfTarget));
      return yield new WaitForSeconds(step);
      percentageOfTarget += step;
      // Display GUI score
      guiText.text = "" + current;
    }

}

public void updateScore (int newScore)
{
    // Send the old score/new score to AnalogScoreProcessing()
    if (oldScore != newScore) 
    {
        StopCoroutine("AnalogScoreProcessing");
        current = oldScore;
        target = newScore;
        StartCoroutine("AnalogScoreProcessing");
    }


}
```

Please be aware this code is pulled directly out of my head so youll probably have to tweek some things here and there but should give you something close to what you desire.
You could/should even scale the GUIText up while the coroutine running for an even more dramatic effect.  Let me know how it goes.

As I side note coroutines are not separate threads in unity they are ran on unity's main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a large difference between `oldScore` and `newScore` then the `print` function in `AnalogScoreProcessing` will be run many times.

You might want to look at using a tween to change the displayed value, as you cannot display more than one value per frame anyway. Or if you're printing to the console then... why are you doing that?

**edit:** have moved [quick and dirty solution a more appropriate question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100884/443019)

Comment: The difference is usually around 150 when it prints. Instead of printing to console I will be displaying each value between oldScore and newScore in the GUI.

Comment: At 60 fps, each increase of 150 points will take 2.5 seconds to complete. That's quite a long time in game play.

Comment: @LooMeenin I've added a quick and dirty solution to my answer.

Comment: @Qubei Please make this a standalone answer as opposed to linking to another answer

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont understandt the Logic behind the function, but cant you just print the score once it changes?

```
if (oldScore != newScore) 
{
    //AnalogScoreProcessing(oldScore, newScore);
    Debug.log(newScore);
}
```

Also you have to set the GUI calls inside the
OnGUI()
function inside your file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my game does now. But I want it to print each value from the old score to the new score for dramatic effect.

Comment: then why do a new Function?

Comment: for(int i = oldScore;i < newScore;i++){ Debug.Log(i);}